# Trying EIP Implicit messaging to EIP device using one available library scapy-cip-enip

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

Exception which I am getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to Forward Open CIP connection:

I know the issue I am getting is something I miss in sending correct forward request parameters including connection parameters and path size format. But not knowing the exact solution.

sending forward_open request:

```
    def forward_open(self):
    """Send a forward open request"""
    cippkt = CIP(service=0x54, path=CIP_Path(wordsize=2, path=b'\x20\x06\x24\x01'))
    cippkt /= test_CIP_ReqForwardOpen(path_wordsize=3, path=b'\x01\x00\x20\x02\x24\x01')
    print("****", self.send_rr_cip(cippkt))
    resppkt = self.recv_enippkt()
    print("*** packet response", resppkt)
    if self.sock is None:
        return
    cippkt = resppkt[CIP]
    print("*** cippkt", cippkt)
    if cippkt.status[0].status != 0:
        logger.error("Failed to Forward Open CIP connection: %r", cippkt.status[0])
        return False
    assert isinstance(cippkt.payload, CIP_RespForwardOpen)
    self.enip_connid = cippkt.payload.OT_network_connection_id
    return True
```

Additional reference class

```
class test_CIP_ConnectionParam(CIP_ConnectionParam):
name = "test_CIP_ConnectionParam"
fields_desc = [
    scapy_all.BitEnumField("owner", 0, 0, {0: "exclusive", 1: "multiple"}),
    scapy_all.BitEnumField("connection_type", 2, 1,
                           {0: "null", 1: "multicast", 2: "point-to-point", 3: "reserved"}),
    scapy_all.BitField("reserved", 0, 1),
    scapy_all.BitEnumField("priority", 2, 2, {0: "low", 1: "high", 2: "scheduled", 3: "urgent"}),
    scapy_all.BitEnumField("connection_size_type", 0, 0, {0: "fixed", 1: "variable"}),
    scapy_all.BitField("connection_size", 8, 4),
]
```

Additional reference class

```
class test_CIP_ReqForwardOpen(CIP_ReqForwardOpen):
"""Forward Open request"""
name = "test_CIP_ReqForwardOpen"
priority = 0
tick_time = 10
timeout_ticks = 240
OT_network_connection_id = 0x06c2939d
TO_network_connection_id = 0x06c2939c
connection_serial_number = 0x939e
vendor_id = 0x00aa
originator_serial_number = 0x504d4153
connection_timeout_multiplier = 2
reserved = 0
OT_rpi = 0x000186A0
OT_connection_param = test_CIP_ConnectionParam(), test_CIP_ConnectionParam
TO_rpi = 0x000186A0
TO_connection_param = test_CIP_ConnectionParam(), test_CIP_ConnectionParam
transport_type = 0xa3
path_wordsize = None
CIP_PathField("path", None, length_from=lambda p: 2 * p.path_wordsize)
```

[Scapy GitHub](https://github.com/scy-phy/scapy-cip-enip)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kdtC.jpg)
Wire shark capture image1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybuR0.jpg)
Wire shark capture image1

Comment: Do you think it could be some problem of endianess? `cippkt` has some handcrafted bytes. I would look at that first. Also, try to capture the data using tcpdump or wireshark. It would also help to have some well-behaving application capture to compare to what your application is sending.

Comment: @PEdroArthur added two captured images. Let me know anything else need to be attachced.

Comment: The `Forward Open [malformed packet]` and `Not enough data` caught my attention. Are you sure the endianess of the bytes you hardcode in `cippkt`'s `path` is correct? See the encoding of the `OT_network_connection_id` and `TO_network_connection_id`.

Comment: @PEdroArthur Yes i know there might be issue due to endianess of the bytes i hardcoded in cippkt's path but what actually should be the correct one that's i am not getting. If you have some idea on this then please help me out here.

Comment: Check your packet class: that’s a 0-bit long field `BitEnumField("owner", 0, 0, ...)`

Comment: @Cukic0d Which packet class you are referring here?

Comment: That’s the first field in your test_CIP_ConnectionParam. Setting a length to 0 doesn’t make sense

Comment: @Cukic0d I have tried with 1-2 as well but as i have seen in a EIP scanner demo tool, two connection points also needed which comes through Assembly Input/Output instance.
Any suggestion, how to add those in this library?

Comment: if anyone can suggest how to proceed, please comments.